# using more than 2 PCs in PCA

Tags: python, pca

I want to use PCA algorithm from scratch, but i want to reduce 784 features to about for example 70 features not 2. what i've tried before is this code below.
In this code for part "Choosing k eigenvectors with the largest eigenvalues" how can i choose k?

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data_train = pd.read_csv('trainData.csv',header=None)
label_train = pd.read_csv('trainLabels.csv',header=None)

data_train = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data_train)

# OR we can do this with one line of numpy for COV:
cov_mat = np.cov(data_train.T)

# Compute the eigen values and vectors using numpy
eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(cov_mat)

# Make a list of (eigenvalue, eigenvector) tuples
eig_pairs = [(np.abs(eig_vals[i]), eig_vecs[:,i]) for i in range(len(eig_vals))]

# Sort the (eigenvalue, eigenvector) tuples from high to low
eig_pairs.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
for i in eig_pairs:
    print(i[0])

#Choosing k eigenvectors with the largest eigenvalues    
matrix_w = np.hstack((eig_pairs[0][1].reshape(784,1), eig_pairs[1][1].reshape(784,1)))
print('Matrix W:\n', matrix_w)
transformed = matrix_w.T.dot(data_train.T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how `matrix_w` is created. The h_stack function takes a tuple of arrays and stacks them horizontally. What you want to do is create a tuple that contains the eigenvectors of the k largest eigenvalues and create the matrix:

```
eigenvectors = tuple([eig_pairs[i][1].reshape(784,1) for i in range(k)])
matrix_w = np.hstack(eigenvectors)
```

Comment: The code snippet looks correct but, in the text portion, do you mean `matrix_w` instead of `matrix_h`

Comment: Of course, you're absolutely right. Thank you, I fixed it :)